# After I installed raspbian, it did not ask for default login. It goes straight to desktop

Tags: raspbian, login

After I installed Raspbian, it did not ask for the default login. It goes straight to the desktop even after restarting. Is this problematic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not problematic, but depending on where your Pi is located it could represent a security threat. I believe the default used to be to boot to the command line, but newer versions seem to default to the GUI with autologin. If you want to change it back to the command line or disable autologin run"

```
sudo raspi-config
```

then choose option **3 Boot Options**

choose one of the following:

- Console
- Console Autologin
- Desktop
- Desktop Autologin

click **Ok** and reboot