# Not asked to login in Jessie Light after installing lightdm, xorg and xinit: why?

Tags: login, jessie-lite, lightdm

I have Jessie Light on my rpi 3 and have further installed `lightdm`, `xorg` and `xinit` partly following the instructions of this [guide](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=133691).
But after booting, I am directly taken to a terminal window without being asked to login with a password.

Why is it so?

This raspberrypi SE [answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/44106/63024) explains how to re-establish the secure login, is there any other mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [a version of `raspi-config`](https://github.com/RPi-Distro/raspi-config/blob/master/raspi-config), the auto-login part is enabled by linking one of several systemd service files from `/lib/systemd/system/` to `/etc/systemd/system/getty.target.wants/getty@tty1.service`.  For auto-login that's `autologin@.service`; for a normal login it's `getty@.service`.

To check which is the case on your system,

```
stat /etc/systemd/system/getty.target.wants/getty@tty1.service
```

It will show an arrow pointing to one of the above possibilities.  If it is the `autologin@.service` file, you can change it the same way `raspi-config` does:

```
sudo ln -fs /lib/systemd/system/getty@.service /etc/systemd/system/getty.target.wants/getty@tty1.service
```

Comment: Just tested; impressive (to my eyes) digging into the system.